# Redirecting and changing URI using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have requests like `https://example.net/files/public/file.html` which I would like to redirect to `https://example.com/domain/public/file.html` via htaccess.
In theory I would have to write an `if` condition and then remove the `files` part from the URI and then redirect to the new domain. But in practice my code doesn't work. 
Has anyone a working example for this type of scenario?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In site root directory of `example.net` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ http://example.com/domain/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I don't want to redirect all the traffic, only traffic which accesses files inside the `files` folder. Also the code above doesn't get rid of the the `files` part in the URI

Comment: I found the error: It has to be `RewriteRule` not `RewriteEngine`. Thanks for your help!